# How to create @ViewChild temporary variable in a method in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, viewchild

I', trying to add a html control dynamically to div and after creating the control I would like to perform operations on it by creating viewchild

```
 @ViewChild('dropDownListReference') myDropDownList: typeOfComponent
```

able to create in class but in a method after generating the control cannot initialize this

```
AddLevelClick() {
var el: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('multi-sort-body');
el.innerHTML = "<div #test1></div>";
 @ViewChild('test1') myDropDownList: typeOfComponent    // Unable to create here
}
```

Any clue on creating ViewChild element locally?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am having the exact same issue and I'm nowhere near a solution

Answer (score 6):

You can't use `ViewChild` with HTML added dynamically.

`ViewChild` only works with component or directive types or template variables added statically to a components template.

You also can't add `@ViewChild()` inside a method. It works only on class-level properties and has to be added statically as well.

Components and directives are also instantiated for HTML statically added to a components template.

You can use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` to add components dynamically though. For an example see [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

Comment: is NgComponentOutlet out ?? I'm using Angular 2.0 Final Release

Comment: Doesn't look like it is https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md